# How to apply function to pandas matrix that knows the location of each cell?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, apply

I need to get information based on each cell in a pandas dataframe that is dependent on the location of that cell within the matrix. This collects scores from 3 cells neighboring 1 cell.

```
scores.append(numpy.array([df.iloc[a-1, b-1], df.iloc[a, b-1], df.iloc[a-1, b]]))
```

I want to run this across the entire matrix for each cell. To do this, I need to get the row name (`b`), column name (`a`), which are numbers representing the location of that cell. How can I access this information in `apply` or `applymap`? I've tried accessing `x.name` and `x.index` but it does not return singular values.

Comment: Can you add some sample data we can copy/paste, and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to get the element position from within `applymap`.

You could, however, use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get previous rows/columns like that:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(25)).reshape(5,5) , columns = list('abcde'))
print(df)
#    a   b   c   d   e
#0   0   1   2   3   4
#1   5   6   7   8   9
#2  10  11  12  13  14
#3  15  16  17  18  19
#4  20  21  22  23  24

stack = np.dstack((df.shift().shift(axis=1), df.shift(axis=1), df.shift()))
pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in stack], columns=df.columns.values)
```

Result:

```
                  a                   b                   c                   d                   e
0   [nan, nan, nan]     [nan, 0.0, nan]     [nan, 1.0, nan]     [nan, 2.0, nan]     [nan, 3.0, nan]
1   [nan, nan, 0.0]     [0.0, 5.0, 1.0]     [1.0, 6.0, 2.0]     [2.0, 7.0, 3.0]     [3.0, 8.0, 4.0]
2   [nan, nan, 5.0]    [5.0, 10.0, 6.0]    [6.0, 11.0, 7.0]    [7.0, 12.0, 8.0]    [8.0, 13.0, 9.0]
3  [nan, nan, 10.0]  [10.0, 15.0, 11.0]  [11.0, 16.0, 12.0]  [12.0, 17.0, 13.0]  [13.0, 18.0, 14.0]
4  [nan, nan, 15.0]  [15.0, 20.0, 16.0]  [16.0, 21.0, 17.0]  [17.0, 22.0, 18.0]  [18.0, 23.0, 19.0]
```